# Android dosen't show me keybord. I use Adapter with Edittext indise AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, adapter, android-alertdialog

AlertDialog works fine, its shows me my adpater, but when I click on the EditText inside my adapter, keybord dosen't open. 
Besides that:

```
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "item:"+item)
```

inside onClickListener dosen't work.

```
public class AddProduct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  String LOG_TAG;
  Button fillFields; 
  ArrayList<String> someArray;
  BoxAdapter boxAdapter;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.newproduct);

    fillFields=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fillFields);
    fillFields.setOnClickListener(this);
    someArray=new ArrayList<String>();
    boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, someArray);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.fillFields:

          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Поля товара");
             alert.setAdapter(boxAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "item:"+item);
                    }});
            alert.create().show();   
    break;
    }
    } 
    }
```

And adapter:

```
 public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  Context ctx;
  LayoutInflater lInflater;
  ArrayList<String> objects;
  OnEditorActionListener myEditorActionListener;
  String LOG_TAG;
  EditText editText;

BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> getFields){
      ctx = context;
        objects = getFields;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
    view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.addproduct_item, parent, false);
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductTextView)).setText(objects.get(position));

      editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductEditText);

    return view;

}

}
```

So, what I am doing wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must show all code and not partial, and better if show your logcat,

But, to force to show keyboard in a dialog, you could use it (i do not know if it is the best way, but, its one way):

```
    YourDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

It depends how you are getting your dialog, but, if it using fragmentDialog or the method (deprecated) onCreateDialog, you should declare your dialog var as final.

Regards.

Comment: I don't use anything but the AlertDialog at all. I have code that I just send in mainActivity. And adapter in another class. That's all. For understanding I will add my code.